# HTML/CSS: How do I make an input field with 2 vertically positioned buttons next to it?

Tags: html, css, layout

This is what I want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aq7zO.jpg

Unfortunately I can't give you the code I've tried because nothing gets even close. It's probably a low hanging fruit question yet I can't find anything that works for some reason :p

If you could give me just some guidelines I'd be much obliged.

Edit, some code, not working:

```
<td>
    <input class="qtyfield"></input>
      <div id="buttons">
        <input class="plusbtn" type='button' value='+'/>
        <br/>
        <input class="minusbtn" type='button' value='-'/>
       </div>
 </td>
```

As you can see it would be in a table row.

And the related CSS:

```
#buttons {
}
.qtyfield {
  width: 30px;
}
.plusbtn {
}
.minusbtn {
}
```

I'm not using bootstrap

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the .qtyfield a float : left and the buttons will stand next to it also adjust some heights. This should work:

```
<td>
    <input class="qtyfield"></input>
    <div id="buttons">
        <input class="plusbtn" type='button' value='+'/>
        <br/>
        input class="minusbtn" type='button' value='-'/>
    </div>
 </td>
```

css:

```
#buttons {
}
.qtyfield {
  height: 34px;
  width: 30px;
  float: left;
}
.plusbtn {
  height: 20px;
  width: 24px;
}
.minusbtn {
  height: 20px;
  width: 24px;
}
```

Comment: Hey man. Your response actually works, thank you a lot. I'm sorry to insist, but this is the closest I'm able to get: https://jsfiddle.net/mjthpgow/ If you could give me a hand that'd be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use a table layout to achieve your buttons, you should use some more proper table syntax!

Try something similar to this for example: https://jsfiddle.net/1wzqLzsc/

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="qtyfield"></input></td>
    <td>
      <div id="buttons">
        <input class="plusbtn" type='button' value='+'/>
        <br/>
        <input class="minusbtn" type='button' value='-'/>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

More on tables: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp

Otherwise you could try using a flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this wrapping the elements in div's.

So the basic idea is there is an outer container for both which is your first div

```
<div></div>
```

Now the next step is to put the elements in their own seperate div's. So your input text will be in one div and your buttons in the other. Once you have the two divs you orient them by making one float to left and one float to right. And you have to also define how much width each one should take.

```
<div>
  <div style="width:50%;float:left">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="test"/>
  </div>
  <div style="width:50%;float:right">
   <input type="button" value="+"/>
  <br/>
  <input type="button" value="-"/>
 </div>
</div>
```